# Cordova alert about server connection

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm getting alert when i run my phonegap app in android emulator. It says:

```
Cordova Facebook connect plugin fail on login!
Dialog error: The connection to the server was unsuccessful.
```

What can be changed for this problem?